# All the ways in which $A_n$ acts on a set $S$ with $m < n$ elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $n \ge 5$, $A_n$ is simple meaning that it has no proper normal subgroups. If this is true, does anyone know all the ways in which $A_n$ acts on a set $S$ with $m < n$ elements. I am slightly confused with this.

Answer (score 1):

There is always the trivial action. Besides that, a nontrivial action of $A_n$ on a set with $m$ elements arises from a homomorphism $\phi:A_n\to S_m$. Since $A_n$ is simple, this homomorphism must be injective. However, $|A_n|=n!/2>n!/n\geq m!=|S_m|$, so no such homomorphism exists. Thus $A_n$ can only act trivially.

Comment: To spell it out: the reason the homomorphism has to be injective is because otherwise it's kernel would be a normal subgroup.